# Get json surrounded by script tag, using bs4 in python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Im using bs4 for Python, I want to get a json from a web page but its like this:

```
<script>
vtex.events.addData({"pageCategory":"Product","pageDepartment":"Calzado","pageUrl":"http://www.taf.com.mx/air-force-1-07-lv8-cu8070-100/p","pageTitle":"AIR FORCE 1 07 LV8 | MASCULINO - tafmx","skuStockOutFromShelf":[],"skuStockOutFromProductDetail":["23312","23313","23314","23316","23325","23326","23327","23328"],"shelfProductIds":["140","141","142","3775","3777","3782","3785","545","17","314","318","530","645","801","822","940"],"accountName":"tafmx","pageFacets":[],"productId":"3829","productReferenceId":"CU8070-100","productEans":["194502172393","194502172409","194502172416","194502172423","194502172430","194502172447","194502172454","194502172461","194502172478","194502172485","194502172492","194502172508","194502172515","194502172522","194502172539","194502172546","194502172553"],"skuStocks":{"23312":0,"23313":0,"23314":0,"23315":11,"23316":0,"23317":19,"23318":29,"23319":22,"23320":12,"23321":7,"23322":9,"23323":15,"23324":14,"23325":0,"23326":0,"23327":0,"23328":0},"productName":"AIR FORCE 1 07 LV8","productBrandId":2000004,"productBrandName":"Nike","productDepartmentId":7,"productDepartmentName":"Calzado","productCategoryId":8,"productCategoryName":"Sneakers","productListPriceFrom":"2199","productListPriceTo":"2199","productPriceFrom":"2199","productPriceTo":"2199","sellerId":"1","sellerIds":"1"});
</script>
```

Using beautifulsoup for python, but there is no class to identify

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the `'script'` tag to find the element:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup('''<script>vtex.events.addData({"pageCategory":"Product","pageDepartment":"Calzado","pageUrl":"http://www.taf.com.mx/air-force-1-07-lv8-cu8070-100/p","pageTitle":"AIR FORCE 1 07 LV8 | MASCULINO - tafmx","skuStockOutFromShelf":[],"skuStockOutFromProductDetail":["23312","23313","23314","23316","23325","23326","23327","23328"],"shelfProductIds":["140","141","142","3775","3777","3782","3785","545","17","314","318","530","645","801","822","940"],"accountName":"tafmx","pageFacets":[],"productId":"3829","productReferenceId":"CU8070-100","productEans":["194502172393","194502172409","194502172416","194502172423","194502172430","194502172447","194502172454","194502172461","194502172478","194502172485","194502172492","194502172508","194502172515","194502172522","194502172539","194502172546","194502172553"],"skuStocks":{"23312":0,"23313":0,"23314":0,"23315":11,"23316":0,"23317":19,"23318":29,"23319":22,"23320":12,"23321":7,"23322":9,"23323":15,"23324":14,"23325":0,"23326":0,"23327":0,"23328":0},"productName":"AIR FORCE 1 07 LV8","productBrandId":2000004,"productBrandName":"Nike","productDepartmentId":7,"productDepartmentName":"Calzado","productCategoryId":8,"productCategoryName":"Sneakers","productListPriceFrom":"2199","productListPriceTo":"2199","productPriceFrom":"2199","productPriceTo":"2199","sellerId":"1","sellerIds":"1"});</script>''', 'html.parser')
    
js_code = soup.find('script').contents[0]
```

`js_code` is then

```
vtex.events.addData({"pageCategory":"Product","pageDepartment":"Calzado","pageUrl":"http://www.taf.com.mx/air-force-1-07-lv8-cu8070-100/p","pageTitle":"AIR FORCE 1 07 LV8 | MASCULINO - tafmx","skuStockOutFromShelf":[],"skuStockOutFromProductDetail":["23312","23313","23314","23316","23325","23326","23327","23328"],"shelfProductIds":["140","141","142","3775","3777","3782","3785","545","17","314","318","530","645","801","822","940"],"accountName":"tafmx","pageFacets":[],"productId":"3829","productReferenceId":"CU8070-100","productEans":["194502172393","194502172409","194502172416","194502172423","194502172430","194502172447","194502172454","194502172461","194502172478","194502172485","194502172492","194502172508","194502172515","194502172522","194502172539","194502172546","194502172553"],"skuStocks":{"23312":0,"23313":0,"23314":0,"23315":11,"23316":0,"23317":19,"23318":29,"23319":22,"23320":12,"23321":7,"23322":9,"23323":15,"23324":14,"23325":0,"23326":0,"23327":0,"23328":0},"productName":"AIR FORCE 1 07 LV8","productBrandId":2000004,"productBrandName":"Nike","productDepartmentId":7,"productDepartmentName":"Calzado","productCategoryId":8,"productCategoryName":"Sneakers","productListPriceFrom":"2199","productListPriceTo":"2199","productPriceFrom":"2199","productPriceTo":"2199","sellerId":"1","sellerIds":"1"});
```

The <strike>tricky</strike> sketchy part is getting the json from it.
I will rarely root for regex for this kind of tasks, but this is a rare one.

```
import re
...
js_code = soup.find('script').contents[0]
print(re.search('{.*}', js_code).group(0))
```

This outputs

```py
{"pageCategory":"Product","pageDepartment":"Calzado","pageUrl":"http://www.taf.com.mx/air-force-1-07-lv8-cu8070-100/p","pageTitle":"AIR FORCE 1 07 LV8 | MASCULINO - tafmx","skuStockOutFromShelf":[],"skuStockOutFromProductDetail":["23312","23313","23314","23316","23325","23326","23327","23328"],"shelfProductIds":["140","141","142","3775","3777","3782","3785","545","17","314","318","530","645","801","822","940"],"accountName":"tafmx","pageFacets":[],"productId":"3829","productReferenceId":"CU8070-100","productEans":["194502172393","194502172409","194502172416","194502172423","194502172430","194502172447","194502172454","194502172461","194502172478","194502172485","194502172492","194502172508","194502172515","194502172522","194502172539","194502172546","194502172553"],"skuStocks":{"23312":0,"23313":0,"23314":0,"23315":11,"23316":0,"23317":19,"23318":29,"23319":22,"23320":12,"23321":7,"23322":9,"23323":15,"23324":14,"23325":0,"23326":0,"23327":0,"23328":0},"productName":"AIR FORCE 1 07 LV8","productBrandId":2000004,"productBrandName":"Nike","productDepartmentId":7,"productDepartmentName":"Calzado","productCategoryId":8,"productCategoryName":"Sneakers","productListPriceFrom":"2199","productListPriceTo":"2199","productPriceFrom":"2199","productPriceTo":"2199","sellerId":"1","sellerIds":"1"}
```

Which can be converted to a Python `dict` using `json.loads`.

```
import json
...
print(json.loads(re.search('{.*}', js_code).group(0)))
```

Outputs

```
{'pageCategory': 'Product', 'pageDepartment': 'Calzado', 'pageUrl': 'http://www.taf.com.mx/air-force-1-07-lv8-cu8070-100/p', 'pageTitle': 'AIR FORCE 1 07 LV8 | MASCULINO - tafmx', 'skuStockOutFromShelf': [], 'skuStockOutFromProductDetail': ['23312', '23313', '23314', '23316', '23325', '23326', '23327', '23328'], 'shelfProductIds': ['140', '141', '142', '3775', '3777', '3782', '3785', '545', '17', '314', '318', '530', '645', '801', '822', '940'], 'accountName': 'tafmx', 'pageFacets': [], 'productId': '3829', 'productReferenceId': 'CU8070-100', 'productEans': ['194502172393', '194502172409', '194502172416', '194502172423', '194502172430', '194502172447', '194502172454', '194502172461', '194502172478', '194502172485', '194502172492', '194502172508', '194502172515', '194502172522', '194502172539', '194502172546', '194502172553'], 'skuStocks': {'23312': 0, '23313': 0, '23314': 0, '23315': 11, '23316': 0, '23317': 19, '23318': 29, '23319': 22, '23320': 12, '23321': 7, '23322': 9, '23323': 15, '23324': 14, '23325': 0, '23326': 0, '23327': 0, '23328': 0}, 'productName': 'AIR FORCE 1 07 LV8', 'productBrandId': 2000004, 'productBrandName': 'Nike', 'productDepartmentId': 7, 'productDepartmentName': 'Calzado', 'productCategoryId': 8, 'productCategoryName': 'Sneakers', 'productListPriceFrom': '2199', 'productListPriceTo': '2199', 'productPriceFrom': '2199', 'productPriceTo': '2199', 'sellerId': '1', 'sellerIds': '1'}
```

Note that you may need to use a more complex regex if the `script` tag contains other things you did not show in the question.

Comment: Thank you, but this only will work if the json is static, right?

Comment: @JesusTorres I'm not sure what you mean by "static". It will work with whatever exists in the `<script>` tag when the `soup` object was created

Comment: I mean what happen if the values of the json change?

Comment: @JesusTorres They can not change, by definition. `soup` loads the source code of the page once.

Comment: thank you one last question, in a html page there is many script tags, how I could identify the script that i want if it doesnt have id or class